# Flask not retrieving env variables when set with bash profile (but it works with export)

Tags: python, bash, flask

I have a Flask application with this code in my config file:

```
class Config(object):
    ...

    POSTGRES_USER = os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER') 
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD') 
    POSTGRES_HOST = os.environ.get('POSTGRES_HOST')
    POSTGRES_DB = os.environ.get('POSTGRES_DB') 
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = f'postgresql://{POSTGRES_USER}:{POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@{POSTGRES_HOST}/{POSTGRES_DB}'
    
     ...
```

This is my bash profile:

```
POSTGRES_USER=pgusername
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pgpassword
POSTGRES_HOST=localhost:5432
POSTGRES_DB=pgdbname
```

Note that I have tried this with and without quotes around the variables (eg., 'pgusername'). I believe no quotes is the correct way to do this.

I set the bash profile using `source ~/.bash_profile` and verify that the variables are set. For example, `echo $POSTGRES_PASSWORD` returns pgpassword as expected.

When I run my Flask application, `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` returns `postgresql://None:None@None/None`. I expect the output to have the env variables rather than `None`.

On the other hand, if I run `export POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pgpassword` in terminal, echo will return pgpassword (as expected), and `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` returns `postgresql://None:pgpassword@None/None`. In this case the postgres password placeholder has been completed with the environment variable I set. I also expect this behavior, since I know I can set env variables directly.

I am unsure why `export` would yield a different result for the Flask app given that `echo` returns the same value for either the bash profile method of setting env variables or export. Maybe I am misunderstanding something about Flask file pathing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`export` means that variable is passed to the child process. `source` without `export` sets variables for the current process only.

Comment: I see.  Seems like the solution is to add this to the bash profile: `export POSTGRES_USER` et al